# How do I turn on ICMP on a D-Link DIR 816 router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am not able to ping another laptop on the same network (WiFi), from my laptop. However, I'm able to do the same when I connect both laptops to my mobile hotspot. So, how do I enable my d-link router to allow ICMP messages?

Comment: Even though it could indeed be your router, you have to keep in mind that windows firewall may also block the ICMP messages. You can test this by seeing if you can ping other devices or the other way around. It is very unlikely that the router is blocking the ICMP messages.

Comment: I tried pinging on my mobile hotspot and it worked. So, it's not a windows firewall issue.

Comment: Again, you are not sure. If you connect to a network, but somehow it is seen as a public network, even if it isn't, windows will put on a lot of restrictions and pinging for example is not possible. Especially in Windows 7, this can happen because you get a popup upon connecting to a new network, and the bottom one says: public network. You need to verify that other computers on the router can ping in order to rule out the router.

Answer (score 0):

In the wireless SSID settings of the router, turn off the `User Isolation` option.
This should allow devices connected to the same network(router) to ping and connect to each other.